# Raspberry Pi unusable

Tags: hardware, software-installation

I don't know why but my raspberry had a problem who make it restart every 15s...

I try to re-install an OS after have format my SD card but it happen again...

I see an little ligthning in the top right, rainbow, Raspberry pi logo some service load and after restart rainbow again.

One mouse and one keyboard is connected.
I find the solution it was my electrical alimentation 5V 550mA who was not enough.

I try an 5V 1A it's works but an little ligthning still show up.

For information the SAFETY INSTRUCTION ask 2.5A

Comment: As you have found the problem it would be useful if you answer the question yourself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there doesn't seem to be a question (answer provided in the query itself)

Comment: a very common problem too - poor power supply ... probably 20% of issues posted here are cause by poor power supply